# Why is nothing happening when I run my C program?

Tags: c, list

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct 
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;  
    int minutes;
    }primaries_date;

typedef struct 
{
    int all_members;
    char *country;
    primaries_date date;
}usa_primaries;

typedef struct node *ptr;

typedef struct node
{
    usa_primaries up;
    ptr next;
}Node;



void add(ptr *hptr, int members, char *con, int month, int day, int     hour, int minutes)
{
    ptr p = NULL;
    ptr q = NULL;
    ptr t;
    t = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(!t)
    {
         printf("Cannot build list");
         exit(0);
    }

    t->up.all_members = members;
    t->up.country = con;
    t->up.date.month = month;
    t->up.date.day = day;
    t->up.date.hour = hour;

   while( (p) )
   {
     if( p->up.date.month >= month || p->up.date.day >= day ||     p->up.date.hour >= hour || p->up.date.minutes >= minutes )
       { 
            q = p;
            p = p->next;
       }
   }

   if(p == *hptr)
   {
        *hptr  = t; /*Resetting head. Assigning to the head t*/
         t->next = p; 
   }
   else
   {
       q->next = t;
       t->next = p;
   }





}

void remove_dates(ptr *hptr, primaries_date date1 , primaries_date date2)
{
    ptr p1 = *hptr;
    ptr p2 = p1;
    while( (p1) && !( (p1->up.date.month == date1.month) &&     (p1->up.date.day == date1.day) && (p1->up.date.hour == date1.hour) && 
           (p1->up.date.minutes==date1.minutes ) ) )
              p1 = p1->next;


          p2 = p1;

    while( (p2) && !( (p2->up.date.month == date2.month) &&    (p2->up.date.day == date2.day) && (p2->up.date.hour == date2.hour) && 
(p2->up.date.minutes==date2.minutes ) ) )
       p1 = p1->next;

    p1->next = p2;

}












void printlist(ptr h)
{
    while(h)
    {
        printf("\n");
   printf("%d %d %d %d %d %s\n", h->up.date.day, h->up.date.month,     h->up.date.hour, h->up.date.minutes, h->up.all_members, h->up.country);
        h = h->next;
    }
}


void freelist(ptr *hptr)
{    
    ptr p;
    while(*hptr)
    {
        p = *hptr;
        *hptr = (*hptr)->next;
        free(p);
   }


}





int main()
{
    ptr h = NULL;
    int month, day, hour, minutes; 
    int all_members; /*Declaration of all_members*/
    char country[256]; 
   char member;

   while( scanf("%d %d %d %d %c  %s",&day,&month,&hour,&minutes,&member,country) == 1)
   {
       if(member == 'Y')
           all_members = 1;
      else
        all_members = 0;
       add(&h,all_members,country,month,day,hour,minutes);
        printlist(h);
   }


freelist(&h);


    return 0;
}
```

There are no compilation errors. However, when I run the program, nothing is happening. 
I thought it might be caused because of the scanf function, since scanf stores the '\n' character when scanning characters (the enter key) but I'm not sure.

Why is nothing happening when I run my program and how can I make it run properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: There are other (unrelated to your *current* question) problems: Think a little bit about the pointer `country` in the `usa_primaries` structure. What do you make it point to? Will the memory you make `country` point to ever change?

Comment: I think I made it point to a character string and I don't think the memory I made country point to ever change :) @Some programmer dude

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible, since I don't know where the problem is, I posted the entire code  :) @ Sourav Ghosh

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` returns how many conversion specifiers it parsed successfully. So it will return something greater than 1 on your input, assuming it's correct. You should compare it against the number of items you actually asked it to read.

And so it also goes without saying, that if you use `scanf` for parsing input, don't read too much at once, or you'll be littering you code with comparisons to magic numbers.

Comment: Thank you :) How can I fix this? @StoryTeller

Comment: @Tree - Read each variable with a separate call to scanf. Then the comparison to 1 will be correct, and you'll know exactly which read it was the failed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean something like:


@StoryTeller

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still don't understand something, how can I know how many loops of the form while(scanf(something) == 1) I should write? because the user inputs values as long as he wishes.
@StoryTeller

Comment: @Tree - Note that I wrote *"parsed successfully"*. It should loop only on input failure. After that continue to the next field.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience, I really appreciate it.
I think I don't understand, do you mean something like this:
while(scanf("%d",day") == 1)
   add(all_members,country,month,day,hour,minutes) ?

Comment: @Tree - No, I mean `while(scanf("%d", &day") != 1) printf("Please enter a day again: "); `

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller